Validity of Referenced Element from Unordered Map after Insert
Recently I came across a warning from MSVC's Code-Analyzer, stating that I was deferencing a pointer that "may be" invalid. I've reduced this to the following simple example:
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> test;

    int &x = test[0];
    int &y = test[1];

    x = y; // line 9
}

This is produces the warnings/errors of:
\Playground2\FileName.cpp(9): error C26489: Don't dereference a pointer that may be invalid: 'y'. 'y' may have been invalidated at line 7 (lifetime.1).
\Playground2\FileName.cpp(9): error C26489: Don't dereference a pointer that may be invalid: 'x'. 'x' may have been invalidated at line 6 (lifetime.1).

I am aware that modifying the container can invalidate the iterators if rehashing is required; however, I'm not using iterators in this case, I am creating references to the values within the map.
If I understand MSVC's implementation correctly, they use a "vector" of list iterators for its buckets, and when rehashing occurs, it would only affect the buckets; not the lists (though, admittedly I am not entirely sure here).
Do these insertions / potential rehashing, also invalidate any references to values within the map? Or is the warning/error generated incorrect?

here you can find a reference of the relevant section in the standard https://stackoverflow.com/a/6442829/4117728.

Looks like the analyser is assuming anytime iterators are invalidated, references are too

Summary of dup: Rehashing invalidates iterators, changes ordering between elements, and changes which buckets elements appear in, but does not invalidate pointers or references to elements.

Addresses are still valid after insertions in the std::unordered_map<> but not for all possible suppressions. If test[0] or test[1] are removed from the std::unordered_map<>,  then using their address becomes an U.B., may be the analyser considers that.
